# Particle Based Collision Detection on GPU

Tags: three.js, webgl, gpgpu

I am trying to make a particle based simulation using the Three.JS particle system. In order to control the vertices I am using fragment shaders so each index in the fragment shader is the position of the particle. I can get velocity from storing the old texture and computing the difference in position. The problem I am confused about is how I would implement collision handling between the particles.

Instead of having each particle go over every other particle in the array (which I can't imagine would work, since it would be like 1,000,000 checks per particle), I was thinking of grouping the points into grid cells and checking the adjacent cells (as I would do on the CPU), however I am unsure how to get group the particles on the GPU. I basically want a texture that is a grid that  contains information about the particles that fall within the area that grid cell covers.

Any advice or strategies would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Grouping  cells is simple. The indicator of which box they remain in can be found directly from their position in 2-3 lines of code at most. Such as dividing x by n-cubes-per-dimension and y by n-cues-per-dimension and multiplication of it by n-cubes before adding to i. i+j*k where i is cube-x index, k is cube per dimension. But if boxes/grid is dynamic then it gets complex.

Comment: Hi I am confused by your comment. So lets say I have 1000 particles and i make a 30x30 to cover the screen (assuming the particles are forced to stay on the screen). Since I am using fragment shaders to control the position of the points, if I want to place them into a grid, do I need to iterate over every pixel within the fragment shader so i have an log(n^2) function (assuming my fragment shader is nxn in dimension). It is silly to do this for each particle since it can be done once and then used by all of the pixels in the fragment shader update step. Should I be doing this on the CPU?

Comment: No, iterate over particles. p.x, p.y values contain information about which boxes they are in. p.x=3.14, p.y=4.15 means this particle is in box 1,1 if box width and height are 5. if p.x=5.1 and p.y=10.1 then this particle is in box 2,3

Comment: so in my fragment shader shader i will nested for loops? at that point I wouldn't need to group them. I am checking every particle anyway. I understand the algorithm you are describing, just my confusing comes with the best way of implementing it on the GPU due to the nature of the massive parallelization

Comment: But I forgot to say that particle size must not be greater than collision scan area, say same as box width. I mean, only center is in a box, not all of it. Since particles are moving, their boxes will change and need recomputed fastest way.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help btw. I think I will probably just use nested for loops in the fragment shader and not bother putting them in grids. I can't see a way of doing a way of optimizing this on the GPU so that I dont have to do the loop for each particle. I basically am trying to avoid having a massive nested for loop called in the fragment shader, but it may be unavoidable. At this point there is no real advantage of even grouping them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151809/discussion-between-m-koval-and-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik).